# Defining $α$ Via The Golden Angle in $\sin(t)·\left(α·φ^{t-{π/2}/π}+β-\frac{α}{φ^{1/2}}\right)^{-1}, \left(α·φ^{t-{π/2}/π}+β-\frac{α}{φ^{1/2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, wave-equation, golden-ratio

**NOTE** $0$ times the golden angle is a $G_1$ point, too, and should give a distance $φ^{-3}$.

**Some of this may be hard to visualize so, see my figs., also see a graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f9ufp0byau).**

**Also, see here for a similar, very nice derivation:**
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520568/708680
See [Here Also for the answerer profile.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue)

(**Note.** My figs. depict the concepts not an actual graph of the wave that I'm looking for, for obvious reasons.)

If $φ=\left(\frac{1+5^{1/2}}{2}\right), α=φ^{-2}, β=1$, then the parametric equations, $x, y=sin(t)·\left(α·φ^{t-{π/2}/π}+β-\frac{α}{φ^{1/2}}\right)^{-1}, \left(α·φ^{t-{π/2}/π}+β-\frac{α}{φ^{1/2}}\right)$ produce a graph where the vertical distances between points of tangency with $x·y=±1$ on alternate sides are powers of φ. (when only positive numbers are graphed, starting at $φ^{-1}$ and proceeding as follows: $ φ^{0}, φ^{1}, φ^{2}, φ^{3}$).

To learn more about the above, see the update to the answer at this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3515756/708680

In the above $α$ is defined in terms of points given by multiples of $π/2$: The distance between any two such points is $α$ times powers of the golden ratio constant (1.618...) (see the above answer / update for more information). I would like to find similar parametric equations where $α$ is defined in terms of points given by multiples of the "Golden Angle" $2·π·φ^{-1}$. These shall be called 'golden points': There are two forms of such points, $g_1$ and $g_2$:

$g_1$ is given by setting $t$ (for an expression of the kind under discussion) to some whole number multiple of the golden angle, (i.e., the golden angle times -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 etc.).

A $g_1$ point's corresponding $g_2$ point has $x$ given by its $g_1$ point. Its $y$ is given by the first (**Lower-down**) point where $x=$ the $x$ coordinate of $g_1$ intersects the 'side' of the wave on which $g_1$ is situated. (By side the following is meant: For the aforementioned equations, $0≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)$ is the back side $\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π$ is the front side, and $\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π+π$ is the back side etc... Momentarily thinking in terms of 3-space may help.)

I want to find equations where the distance between any two 'golden 'points' $g_1$ and $g_2$ is a power of $φ$ times $α$ such that the first such distance is $φ^{-1}$ for positive numbers; proceeding: $φ^{0}, φ^{1}, φ^{2}, φ^{3}$. These equations should have the following attributes, too:

**0.** Be of the form: $x,y=f(t)^{-1}·sin(t), f(t)$. (To add clarity, for the original equations, this $f(t)$ was $f(t)=\left(α·φ^{t-{π/2}/π}+β-\frac{α}{φ^{1/2}}\right)$.

**1.** Start at $(0, 1)$ for positive and negative numbers.

**2.** Have points of tangency to $x·y=±1$ (as a result of **0.**).

**3.** Maintain a smooth, sinusoidal, 2-D spiral nature throughout.

**4.** Be written in terms of $sin(t)$.

Thanks so much for the help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This problem is significantly different than your earlier ones, as there's no longer a natural/elegant relationship between the pairs of points that are supposed to be powers-of-$\phi$ apart. Also, it bothers me that, for $g_1$ points "close to" a hyperbola (that is, when multiples of your "golden angle" are "close to" odd multiples of $\pi$), the choice of corresponding $g_2$ depends upon an *accident* of whether the $g_1$ is on the "front" or "back" of the figure, and there's a pretty big gap between the candidate $y$-values; this isn't quite a continuity problem, but it *feels* like one.

Comment: Moreover, I don't personally see anything particularly special in your definition of "golden angle" that would impact the situation. Perhaps it's a failure of intuition on my part, but it seems that you might as well just take the angle to be some arbitrary irrational multiple of $\pi$; but then there's no reason to expect to get the powers-of-$\phi$ offsets that you want.

Comment: In any case, you've posted numerous questions on this topic, refining your thinking and revising what it is you're after. I believe I'll be sitting this iteration out.

Comment: @Blue I understand. I'll still be giving you the 100 bounty for the other work. My reason for posting this one is that I took very exact measurements on the original, and this is an absolutely perfect fit.

Comment: In terms of $g_1$ and $g_2$ the exact values are given by solving for a Cartesian version of a sine wave of this kind and then plugging in the $g_1$ $x$ values. One of the solutions will be $g_2$. You could probably then also manipulate these equations to only yield one solution at $x=g_1$.

Comment: Now, even though you won't be solving this, you still ought to understand it, because it's a very pretty, interesting thing that I'm certain you'll find interesting. So here goes:

Comment: I was given a new copy of the graph in which it was clear that the author meant it to be a helix (broken lines were used on the back). This lead me to think about why your derivation was slightly out of phase and I realized that if you mapped points in terms of the golden angle, you'd get a perfect fit. This was so cool!

Comment: Actually, I'm going to move this into an 'answer' so that I have the space to give a good account of the problem, so see beneath! Thank you!

Comment: O, @Blue, you 'ought' to link someone's profile if you use their work? I read such.

Comment: @Blue, would you mind helping me out by telling me what form the you think the equations would take? Despite several posts, various iterations, and hours of work I've had no luck; but I think with the form, I can use 'brute force' to get the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**This has an error in it: we can't fully forget about x(t), because of slight de-phasing; however, what I said holds as a sort of approximation that moves us closer.**

This isn't an answer, but rather a more thorough examination of the question. The answerer to a prior iteration of this question (and presumably other persons) seemed to find, in essence, that this problem is overly arbitrary. I hope to show why this is not the case, and to add greater insight.

As we all know by now (that is all who have been following these posts) $x, y=\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{f(t)}\right), f(t)$ meets and is tangent to the hyperbola(s) $x·y=±1$.

Consequently, we can really forget about $x(t)$ for this problem as it's given by $y(t)$. Indeed, because of this relation, we can forget about the hyperbola(s), too, and think about the problem in terms of a wave of the form $x, y=\sin(t), f(t)$. All that matters is $f(t)$.

Now, this problem is probably easier to solve in 2-D; but it's probably going to be easier to make sense of it in 3-D.

To visualize what's meant to be happening, lets imagine a helix given by $x, y, z=\sin(t), \cos(t), f(t)$, where $f(t)$ is the function I'm looking for. **(**$f(t)$ will presumably take the form $µ^{t·ζ}$ where $µ$ is some positive, real number and $ζ$ is some real number. Or some modification thereof, obviously keeping in mind that it should retain a starting point for positive and negative numbers at $(0, 1)$ **in 2-D**.**)**

Alright, the equations for this helix should allow us to do the following:

We'll enter $2·π·φ^{-1}$ ($φ$ being $1.618..$) into these equations to get a point. Next we'll draw an imaginary line down from this point until it touches the closest lower loop.

Aright, now we can depart from any kind of formal thought, imagine this situation in the real world. Imagine moving this imaginary 'line' up the helix: It will lengthen gradually until it is its original length times $φ$ at $2·(2·π·φ^{-1})$. And so on in the same way for every multiple.

So, returning to the actual equations I'm looking for; this $z(t)$ or in 2-D $y(t)$ will allow us to create a triple $φ$ curve: The distance between loops grows by $φ$ every time the angle is a multiple of the $φ$ angle, and the whole thing moves closer and closer to the $y$ axis in the same way.

Now, **note that** the original equations, the ones in the update linked above, do the same exact thing (when converted to 3-D), they grow the distance between loops, only they do this via $π/2$.

I hope this yielded some insight.