# Parametric Equations for A 2-D Helix Where The Distance Between Loops are Powers of $φ$ at Multiples of The Golden Angle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, parametric, wave-equation, golden-ratio

I want to find parametric equations for a sine-wave ('2-D helix') of the form $x, y=\sin(t), f(t)$, where $f(t)$ causes the expression to:

**1.** Start at **(0, 1)** (for positive and negative numbers).

**2.** Sets the distance $γ$ between loops of the 'helix' to powers of the golden ratio constant (the first such distance being $φ^{-1}$ for positive numbers and proceeding $φ^{0}, φ^{1}, φ^{2}...$ for positive numbers) at multiples of the golden angle input into the equations (i.e., $2·π·φ^{-1}$). **The first such distance defined wholly by positive numbers is actually at:** $2(2·π·φ^{-1})$ (The pattern **must** also apply to negative numbers in the same way, i.e.,  $φ^{-2}, φ^{-3}, φ^{-4}...$ (Note the special cases of $γ=φ^{-2}$ and $γ=φ^{-3}$ which are not defined entirely in terms of either positive or negative values for $t$.)

**It must be noted that**; the term '2-D helix' was used here because the problem is probably best grasped by thinking in 3-D for a moment. However, there's absolutely no need to solve this in 3-D: 3-D thinking is just a tool for clearer thought, in this case: See a graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bh1hz78ytm) to gain greater insight into what I'm talking about. **Also see my fig.**

(**Note that** my fig. and graph show the concepts, obviously, they don't depict the graph of the expression I want as I don't have it. So, don't, for instance, try to match your graph up to my fig.'s actual proportions....)

I suspect that my graph and fig. and the somewhat informal description presented above, will give most readers the insights needed to address this problem, so long as they **read everything carefully.** However, if you don't find this to be true, see the notes beneath (the fig.) for more formal definitions, further context, more exact stipulations, and more:

[image]

**A:** *Equation Requirements:*

The equations must:

**1.** Be written $\sin(t), f(t)$: In other words, you can't do anything to $x(t)$; $x(t)$ must be just $\sin(t)$; the answer can't involve manipulating $x(t)$ at all.

**2.** Start at **(0, 1)** for positive and negative numbers.

**3.** Be a sine-wave / 2-D helix / sine-like curve **NOT** any random curve that can hit the correct points; it must be smooth, continuous, and, in 3-D, be a curve obtained by (metaphorically) winding a string up a cylinder.

**4.** Have $γ$ equal $φ^{-1}$ at $2·(2·π·φ^{-1})$ and go on $φ^{0}, φ^{1}, φ^{2}..$ for every positive, whole number multiple of the golden angle. Similarly for negative whole number multiples, noting the special cases of $γ=φ^{-2}$ and $γ=φ^{-3}$.

**5.** Use $\sin(t)$ **Not** $\cos(t)$.

**B:** Definition of where $γ$ should equal powers of $φ$:

**1.** $γ$ must equal powers of $φ$ at 'Golden points,' $g_1$ and $g_2$ the first such points defined wholly by positive values of $t$ yielding $γ=φ^{-1}$.

**2.** $g_1$ points are: Given by setting $t$ (for an expression of the kind under discussion) to some whole number multiple of the golden angle.

**3.** A $g_1$ point's corresponding $g_2$ point has $x$ given by its $g_1$ point. Its $y$ is given by the first (**Lower-down**) point where $x=$ the $x$ coordinate of $g_1$ intersects the 'side' of the wave on which $g_1$ is situated. (By side the following is meant: For the aforementioned equations, $0≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)$ is the back side $\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π$ is the front side, and $\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π≤t≤\left(\frac{π}{2}\right)+π+π$ is the back side etc... Momentarily thinking in terms of 3-space may help.)

**C:** Other Definitions:

**1.** $φ=\left(\frac{1+5^{1/2}}{2}\right)$

**2.** $γ=$ (in 3-D) the horizontal distance between a point on a loop of a cylindrical helix and another point on a loop (the 'next' loop) above or beneath it, with the same $x,z$ as the first.

**3.** The Golden Angle is: $2·π·φ^{-1}$

D: Context:

**1.** an answer to this question will be equivalent to answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522919/defining-%CE%B1-via-the-golden-angle-in-sint-left%CE%B1-%CF%86t-%CF%80-2-%CF%80%CE%B2-frac%CE%B1%CF%86). But in this case, I took all extraneous, distracting factors out of the fundamental question leaving only what's really important.

**2.** I've been trying to solve this question for a very long time (more than half a year): I'm willing to award a large bounty (as soon as I can) to anyone who can solve it. Or help them however else I can. So, I would be extremely thankful for some help.

**3.** Please ask me if you don't understand some aspect of this!

**4.** See [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3515756/708680) and [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520568/708680) for similar answers that may give clues! **For the first link, see the update to the answer.**

**5.** If you can't answer this but find the idea cool, I'd be thankful if you'd share it with someone who can.

Thank you all! Let's solve this!

Comment: Do let me know if anything is ill-defined or if you have any questions! Thank you.

Comment: **Also,** if you don't want to solve this but know how to, it would be great if you could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to follow, I think in trying to provide a lot of detail you're just adding extra complication. $\gamma$ is the pitch, should it continuously increase or increase in steps? If increasing in steps, where are the steps (at what point in each oscillation)? If continuous, is something like $f(t)=e^{\phi t/(2\pi)}$ appropriate?

Comment: Actually it's just $(\sin(t),\phi^{t/2\pi})$.

Comment: @David I'm sorry it's hard to follow. A well-known user told me that everything must be rigorously defined. If you want to know what I want study my fig. It does not depict the helix I want, but rather a similar one where I represent what the values at the points should be.

Comment: For example let's take the two dashed curves connected by the $\phi^2$. Are they distance $\phi^2$ apart everywhere along the dashed sections? (I mean, *should* they be the same distance apart)

Comment: @David, the black dotted lines are lengths.

Comment: They are indeed $ϕ^{2}$ apart.

Comment: @David Do let me know if you can derive it and I'll make 5 good quality posts a day until I can give you a bounty of 100 for the answer, if you'd like. (Other users will confirm that I'll really do so).

Comment: I don't really mind about rep, I'll keep playing with it and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @David, thank you! It's very kind of you! It is tricky.

Comment: Oh, @David, I misread something, it's the vertical distance downward to the next oscillation, not upward.

Comment: @David, do let me know when you read the comment above this. As I'd hate for you to spend a lot of time on something based on a mistake. For both our sake!

Comment: Noted, fortunately I don't think it's a huge difference downwards vs upwards.

Comment: Thanks; good! It would indeed make a large difference in this case; however. Thank you! The reason, BTW, is that up would massively de-phase things.

Comment: I meant in terms of the equation. I'll have to come back to this tomorrow, I have something that promising at the moment with $f(t)$ of the form $\phi^{\phi t/(2\pi)}$ but it needs some more constants/tweaking.

Comment: @David Awesome!! I really am so thankful! I bet it will be epic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can describe your curve parametrically by 
$(x(t),y(t))=\left(\sin(t),f(t)\right)$, where
$$f(t)=\frac{\phi^{\phi-3}}{\phi^\phi-1}\left(\phi^{\frac{\phi t}{2\pi}}-1\right)+1.$$

To verify, pick time $t_k=\frac{2\pi k}{\phi}$. The difference between $f(t_k)$ and $f(t_k-2\pi)$ should be $d_k=\phi^{k-3}$. So

$$\begin{align}
f(t_k)-f(t_k-2\pi)&=\frac{\phi^{\phi-3}}{\phi^\phi-1}\left(\phi^{\frac{\phi t_k}{2\pi}}-\phi^{\frac{\phi(t_k-2\pi)}{2\pi}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\phi^{\phi-3}}{\phi^\phi-1}\left(\phi^{k}-\phi^{k-\phi}\right)\\
&=\frac{\phi^{k-3}}{\phi^\phi-1}\left(\phi^\phi-1\right)\\
&=\phi^{k-3}=d_k
\end{align}$$
as required.

I came up with this by considering that decreasing $t_k$ by $2\pi k/\phi$ decreases the pitch by a factor of $\phi$, so we needed something like $\phi$ to the power of $k$, and at times $t_k$, $k=\phi t_k/(2\pi)$, so set the power as $\phi t/(2\pi)$. Then it was just a matter of finding the right coefficient in front of the $\phi^{\phi t/(2\pi)}$, which I found by doing the reverse of the verification above to find the appropriate $c$ in $c\phi^{\phi t/(2\pi)}$. Finally it had to be shifted vertically a bit to ensure $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Great work! I can confirm that it works. You're a genius! Totally beautiful. Would you mind if I asked one more question?

Comment: I made this post in the hope that if I did this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sl84fgaxnx (I showed two ways of doing it.) Then I would get a nice 'hyperbolic' curve while retaining the attributes that you derived a function for. Unfortunately, this was not the case. It's no fault of your work, but instead an issue in my thought process. Do you know why this is and what to do about it?

Comment: BTW, as I said, I want to do something nice for you. So, if you don't care about reputation, let me know of something else if you'd like, for instance I know how to do CAD and graphic design and am pretty good at a number of things. So, if you ever need any help in these regards I'd be happy to try an repay you!

Comment: See here for a more complete description of my question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527645/converting-a-helix-with-pitch-increasing-at-multiples-of-an-angle-to-hyperbolic